# Wrong memory speed with Supermicro X11SAE

Tags: memory, clockspeed, supermicro

I have a PC with a Supermicro X11SAE, one Samsung M391A2K43BB1-CRC memory module and a Xeon E3-1230 v5 CPU.

According to the datasheet, the memory module should run at 1200 MHz (DDR4-2400). CPU-Z (tab "SPD") under Windows 7 Pro x64 also shows "Max Bandwidth: DDR4-2400 (1200 MHz)".

However, when the board is booting (before the OS is loading), it shows that it is running the memory at 1066 MHz (actually, it says 2133 MHz). Not surprisingly, CPU-Z (tab "Memory") under Windows 7 Pro x64 also shows "DRAM Frequency: 1066 MHz".

What could be the reason that the mainboard does not operate the memory at the maximum possible frequency?

Note: I have installed the newest BIOS (2.3, build date 2018-06-21) and the newest drivers / INF updates under Windows, and I have configured the BIOS to determine the RAM frequency automatically.

I am aware that I could force the mainboard to operate the RAM at 1200 / 2400 MHz by configuring the BIOS accordingly, but I am concerned that the board won't run stable (or is it stably :-)?) any more then (given that it obviously is not able to log in the RAM in the correct way automatically).

Comment: What is your CPU?

Comment: It is a Xeon E3-1230 v5. I have added that information to my question. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xeon E3-1230 v5 does not support DDR4-2400 memory.

Per the Intel Ark page for [Xeon E3-1230 v5](https://ark.intel.com/products/88182/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1230-v5-8M-Cache-3_40-GHz)

> Memory Types: DDR4-1866/2133

Your memory is operating at the highest *compatible* speed supported by both your CPU and RAM.

You *might* be able to force the higher speed and it might work, but it would be unsupported and could cause memory corruption or an unstable system.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, +1 and accepted. I thought I had checked that when choosing the CPU, but obviously, I hadn't. And of course, I won't try to overclock (I have never done that because stability is more important to me than a gain in speed which you hardly will notice).